# Facebook React to render different components based on url hash

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

How can I make the react class render based on the changed hash url?

This is what my react code looks like now:

```
module.exports = React.createClass {   render: () ->
    div {},
      div {},
        a { href: '#testhash' }, 'test link'
      div {},
        if (window.location.hash.substring(1) is 'testhash')
          'this is a test'
        else
          'this is a sentence'
}
```

but it only works once (i.e. what ever the first url was - with or without the hashtag).

How can I make it so that the url hash change (clicking on the href) is picked up on click?

That is, then the `test link` is clicked, the page should say `this is a test` instead of `this is a sentence`.

Is there a simpler way to do this without having to add state values and button functions?

Do I need to use mixins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple mixin for this.  The mixin internally uses state and event listeners, however this isn't exposed to your component.  All your component knows about are the two public methods:

- `this.getHash()` → `String`
- `this.isHash(String)` → `Boolean`

```coffeescript
React.createClass {
  mixins: [HashMixin()]
  render: () ->
    div {},
      div {},
        a { href: '#testhash' }, 'test link'
      div {},
        if @isHash 'testhash'
          'this is a test'
        else
          'this is a sentence'
}
```

```coffeescript
# provides getHash() to get the current hash
# provides isHash(hash) to test for equality with a hash
HashMixin = () ->
  getState = () -> {__hash: window.location.hash.slice(1)}

  getHash: () -> @state.__hash
  isHash: (hash) -> @state.__hash is hash
  getInitialState: getState

  componentDidMount: () -> 
    window.addEventListener 'hashchange', @__update_hash_state, false
  componentWillUnmount: () -> 
    window.removeEventListener 'hashchange', @__update_hash_state, false

  __update_hash_state: () -> @setState getState()
```

For more serious projects, you should use an existing routing library.  The most popular for react is react-router.  You can also use routers not specific to react, and use a mixin wire them to your components (e.g. director or backbone's router).